# Помогите с Post запросом retrofit не могу правильно сделать валидацию ключей с шифрованием

Tags: java, android, retrofit

```
curl -X POST \
     -d "command=returnBalances&nonce=154264078495300" \
     -H "Key: 7BCLAZQZ-HKLK9K6U-3MP1RNV9-2LS1L33J" \
     -H "Sign: 2a7849ecf...ae71161c8e9a364e21d9de9" \
     https://poloniex.com/tradingApi
```

мой запрос \

```
 @FormUrlEncoded\
    @Headers("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded")\
    @POST("tradingApi")\
    Single<Map<String,String>> returnBalance(@Field ("Key")String key, @Field ("Sign") String sign);
```

с помощью сторонней программы все работает, значит кей, сигн, рабочие[image: введите сюда описание изображения] ретрофитом не могу сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо вместо `@Field` использовать `@Header` - т.к. у вас `Key` и `Sign` - заголовки, а не параметры запроса

---

Если вы получаете от сервера `[error=Invalid command.]` то надо смотреть на то, какие параметры вы посылаете. У вас параметров вообще нет, вот сервер и ругается.

Comment: Юрий, снова выручаете спасибо вам, application/x-www-form-urlencoded обязательное условие ответа , если заполнять обычными hearder он говорит об ошибке валидации

Comment: Пожалуйста) Если ответ вам помог - вы можете его отметить галочкой слева от тела ответа)

Comment: К сожалению не работает если делаю так     @Headers("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded")\
    @POST("tradingApi")
    Single<Map<String,String>> returnBalance(@Header ("Key") String key,@Header("Sign" )String sing,@Body String body);

Comment: не могу использовать вместе FormUrlEncoded u @Header, если пишу через header получаю [error=Invalid command.], если через Field неправильные логин или пароль

Comment: Странно должно работать. Возможно, надо убрать лишний заголовок - `@Headers("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded")` он и так должен проставляться аннотацией `@FormUrlEncoded`

Comment: а если использовать FormUrlEncoded то @Header уже нельзя студио ругается , говорит только Fields

Comment: Тогда наоборот попробуйте - оставить @Headers("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded") и убрать @FormUrlEncoded

Comment: пробовал, получаю [error=Invalid command.],

Comment: Возможно, дело в том, что у вас в примере запроса есть параметр с командой, а в запросе ретрофита его нет? Что если его добавить?

Comment: Спасибо Юрий помогло, без вас мне пришлось бы думать еще много времени)

Comment: Пожалуйста) Я обновил ответ - можете принять его галочкой слева от тела ответа, если он вам помог)

Comment: не помогло, там же ошибка вываливается

Comment: I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> POST https://poloniex.com/tradingApi 
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Content-Length: 47
    Key: J9FN34KH-M6U4MKHH-THJA9JHB-3PMMYZOF
    Sign: 74d4be538....45te
    "command=returnBalances&nonce=1617012253559200"
    --> END POST (47-byte body)

Comment: и по итогу {"error":"Invalid command."} Какой то косяк с @Body у меня в retrofit

Comment: @POST("tradingApi")
    Call<Map<String,String>> returnBalance( @Header("Key") String key,@Header("Sign" ) String sign,@Header("Content-Type")String type, @Body String parol);

Comment: Вы меня запутали. Вы уже пару раз сказали, что всё работает, а потом говорите, что нет... Это странно. Попробуйте вот так:  `@FormUrlEncoded @POST("tradingApi") Call<Map<String,String>> returnBalance( @Header("Key") String key,@Header("Sign" ) String sign, @Field ("command")String command, @Field ("nonce") String nonce);`

Comment: Сработало окончательно, просто вечером тестировал прошлый ответ, он ошибку показывал в запросе и я подумал что все работает осталось исправить ошибку запроса, а с утра разобрал и оказалось что показалось)

Comment: Т.е. теперь оно работает - на запрос приходят ожидаемые данные?

Comment: Да работает, как и ожидается